# Why is code in PLSQL not executing after "exception" part?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracle18c

So I made a bug in which I didn't put execute immediate inside nested begin-end block so my code didn't work. So basically I had

```
begin
 execute immediate 'select * from sales';
 exception when others then null;
 dbms_output.put_line(123);
end;
```

Dbms_output did not print "123" and I figured out I need to put execute immediate inside begin-end. I want to be sure, so my question is why is code not executing after exception part even though exception is not raised?

Comment: Cannot replicate as an exception is thrown. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87496e943fec296be98eab4d0438c9c2)

Comment: I'm currently working in DataGrip, here is a picture [example](https://ibb.co/xSxXCh2)
@MT0

Comment: Try running `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` to show the console output before you run the PL/SQL anonymous block.

Comment: @MT0 That command is not valid in DataGrip but that is not a problem. My output works fine, you can see in the picture that I have it on. Left bottom corner there is icon with hamburger menu which is highlighted. When I wrap execute immediate and exception part in nested begin-end everything works fine

Comment: your dbms_output is part of the exception, it will be executed after the 'null' part which does nothing. Do you have a table called sales? if Yes, then your execute immediate will not raise an error, and so dbms_output will not get executed.

Comment: @gsalem of course it raises an exception because the `Into... ` clause is missing.

Comment: @gsalem I think you are actually correct. This is just example, it is not my real code. In my code I have into clause, but I think the code is treated like a part of exception. Everything inside exception and end; is treated as a part of exception code.

Comment: @wemfried, no it does not raise an exception if there's no into clause. comment the exception line in dbfiddle, and try it (after replacing sales with dual)

Comment: @gsalem what is odd to me is that if I modify code above to get exception, for example no_data_found, my code actually runs. So code above doesn't output anything if exception is not raised and if exception is raised it outputs 123. That is why I'm confused on how it actually works. [exception not raised](https://postimg.cc/XZn4t61W) and [exception raised](https://postimg.cc/k2mmtdmS). Isn't this disproving your theory? That is what I found very odd to happen.

Comment: Fran, everything between ‘exceptions’ and ‘end’ is part of the exception code. If you want  to do something after that, then you need two code blocks.

Comment: @gsalem Yeah, I now understand it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is code not executing after exception part even though exception is not raised?

The reason is very simple - `dbms_output.put_line` in the question is not in *"after exception part"*.

Properly indented code is equivalent to:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'select * from dual';
exception when others then 
    null;
    dbms_output.put_line(123);
end;
/
```

Exception block is everything between `EXCEPTIONS` and `END;` and will be executed if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things in play here - parsing and execution.

If the table does not exist, then the statement cannot be parsed, and hence we'll get an exception immediately.

```
SQL> begin
  2     execute immediate 'select * from xxxx';
  3  end;
  4  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

However, if the table DOES exist then the parse will be fine.  Because you never specified an INTO that is *all* we do. We never needed to execute and commence the fetch phase and thus no error occurred.  An easy to way to see that we never executed the statement is with something like

```
SQL> begin
  2     execute immediate 'select 1/count(*) from dual where 1=2';
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If we had executed, then we'd expect a divide by zero error to come out. The moment we see an INTO, then we'll need to fetch (which will require an execution).

Comment: I get that but code above is just example,in my actual code I have into. Please look at my last comment above in source question comments where I explained what I found very odd to happen. At least to me.

Comment: your only evidence of working or not is seeing the output of dbms_output.put_line.  But here is a fundamental you must understand. dbms_output.put_line does _not_ write to the console, it writes to an internal buffer. Then _on completion of the procedured_, the calling client _may_ (or may not) choose what to do with that buffer.  Some clients always ignore it.  sqlplus will choose to process and display it _if and only if_ you have issued the 'set serverout on' command.

Comment: @EdStevens I get that, you are right. But how can same code work when exception is raised and not when exception is not raised? So when exception is raised DataGrip displays internal buffer and when exception is not raised it ignores it?